# Appending values to TTK Combobox['values'] without reloading combobox

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

I need to add values to a ttk.combobox without reloading the whole thing. The current selection on the GUI should not be reloaded when values are added to it.

I need something like this:

```
for string in listofstrings:
    if string not in self.combobox1['values']:
        self.combobox1['values'].append(string)
```

When I try it like this, I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'

(as expected).

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about:

```
if string not in self.combobox1['values']:
    self.combobox1['values'] = (*self.combobox1['values'], string)
```

Or alternatively:

```
if string not in self.combobox1['values']:
    self.combobox1['values'] += (string,)
```

Comment: Went for the first option. Works like a charm.
Thanks

Comment: the first option does "reload the whole thing'

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this post while looking for a way to append items to a Combobox. I am loading values from a spreadsheet. I created a list and then added items in a loop. After the loop is over, all the values are assigned to a Combobox. I hope this helps someone.

```
Combobox1.delete(0, END)
wb = load_workbook("types.xlsx")
ws = wb.active
r = 1
string=['']

for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, min_col=1):
    val=str(ws.cell(row=r, column=1).value)
    string.append(val)
    r = r + 1

Combobox1['values'] = string
wb.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
values = ('Select One',)
for i in symbols_from:
    values = values + (i,)

combo_symbol_name_from['values'] = values
combo_symbol_name_from.current(0)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.